# Aligning within CSS

Tags: html, css

Here are the snippets from my HTML and CSS: [jSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/00vp40dt/1/)

HTML:

```
<div id="leftWrapper">
    <div id="navigation">
        <a href="#">
            <div id="previousImage" class="navButton">&lt;</div>
        </a>

        <div id="findImage">
            <input type="text">
        </div>

        <a href="#">
            <div id="nextImage" class="navButton">&gt;</div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url("http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css");

#leftWrapper {
  float:left;
}

#leftWrapper {
  width:40%;
  background-color: red;
}

#navigation {
  padding-top: 0px;
  width: 300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 80px;
  background-color: #bada55;
}

#navigation * {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

#findImage {
  width: 212px;
}

.navButton {
  height: 40px;
  width:40px;
  line-height: 40px;
}
```

My question is: How do I align #navigation (arrows and input) with the green box? It whould be within it, but it always seems to be outside.

### Edit: I want arrows to be shown each one on the one side of input field, and both anrrows and input field to be vertically aligned with the green box. So, something like this:

### | < inputhere > |

Comment: What is it that you want to display? I'm guessing that you want the `<input>` horizontally and vertically centred within the green `#navigation <div>`, with the left and right arrows on either side of the `<input>` (but with the arrows still within the green `#navigation <div>`). Is that right, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: You could put `vertical-align: top;` inside your #navigation * {}` selector. Then use `vertical-align: middle;` inside your `#findImage {}` selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you what you're looking for. We're using vertical align to position the elements vertically. The input tag is being set to 100% width a negative margin to override the default 2px inset border that is applied in most browsers.

CSS:

```
@import url("http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset.css"); // This should probably be hosted locally

#leftWrapper {
    float:left;
}

#leftWrapper {
    width:40%;
    background-color: red;
}

#navigation {
    padding-top: 0px;
    width: 300px;
    margin:0 auto;
    height: 40px;
    line-height: 40px;
    background-color: #bada55;
}

#navigation * {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#findImage {
    width: 212px;
}

#findImage input {
    width:100%;
    height:28px;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 2px inset;
    margin-left:-2px;
}

.navButton {
    height: 40px;
    width:40px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7d53Lea6/

Comment: A little explanation would be helpful. Code dumps provide no information for future visitors.

Comment: Thanx, now I see that line-height in #navigation... -.-'
Explanation: my line-height was double the size of height in #navigation.

Comment: Line-height was part of the issue. The input was also overflowing it's container.

Answer (score 0):

I've done what I can to simplify both the markup and the styling:

```css
form {
    width: 300px;
    height: 28px;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding: 6px 0 6px 24px;
    background-color: #bada55;
}

form a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

input {
    height: 20px;
    line-height:20px;
}

form a, input {
    display:inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight:900;
}
```

```html
<form>
    <a href="#" id="previousImage" class="navButton">&lt;</a>
        <input type="text" id="findImage" class="findImage" name="findImage" />
    <a href="#" id="nextImage" class="navButton">&gt;</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score -3):

I don't mean to be rude, but I think you should properly learn HTML, and CSS. Whatever you do, don't take someone else's work. Because you WILL end up being more confused than ever.

I know some people can't read markup, and this is why I suggest you don't take, and use something you don't understand.

Your css is missing more css, and your HTML is missing more HTML. You're not even using the `<body>` tag, and you should be using the `<body>` tag.

I don't see a navigation in your HTML. Nothing is linked to the HTML you're showing.

Your HTML:

```
<div id="navigation">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="previousImage" class="navButton">&lt;</div>
    </a>

    <div id="findImage">
        <input type="text">
    </div>

    <a href="#">
        <div id="nextImage" class="navButton">&gt;</div>
    </a>
</div>
```

My HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
<a href="friends.html">friends</a>
<a href="foods.html">foods</a>
<a href="schools.html">schools</a>
<a href="candy.html">candy</a>
<a href="family.html">family</a>
</div>
```

If you carefully look at what's between the navigation div, then you should see something that's linked to the markup, but I don't see anything that's linked with your HTML.

You're also showing part of HTML that's used to make an empty text field to make a form, but I think this HTML is useless, for you since you're missing a lot of markup, and code to make a form.

Your HTML:

```
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Here are the snippets...
**THE SNIPPETS**

Comment: @Franco Do you think it is possible that the OP only posted the section of HTML they were having trouble with?

Comment: I think the OP copied some HTML, and CSS that does not belong to him, or her. I know some people do this, and these people want to learn something without learning it the right way.